# Alias Table name - Postgres database?

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js, pgadmin

I am using `PostGreSql as database`, I have `tables in pgAdmin`.

I want to set as alias to table `myData`. I have tried using `AS` or `ALIAS` but nothing works for me.

Here is my class

```
class Product extends Model{
constructor(conn, schema){
        super(conn, schema, "product", {
                // fields
       },true);
   }

 // function
  async getNextData() {
   try {
   const data = await this._conn.query(`
   select  *
   from  ${this._schema}."terms", ${this._schema}."myData"  ------>>>> ALIAS THIS TABLE
   where (${this._schema}."myData"."firstName" = ${this._schema}."yourData"."lastName")}
 }
}
```

Comment: You are not using sequelize. Those configurations don't represent the use of the library.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `pgAdmin` as it is just a client and you are querying the Postgres server not `pgAdmin`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ok got it, can you help me as to why alias does not work in my case? Thanks